# ¿ Cómo evitar que el valueChanges del formControl no escuche al iniciar la view en Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un `reactive form` con el campo **username**, mientras el usuario escribe el username verifico si existe. Si existe, en la `view` le informo que es valido, caso contrario que no es valido. El problema es que al iniciar la view, el `input` username esta vacio y como el `valueChanges` del `formControl('username')` ya esta escuchando los cambios devuelve `false`, por lo tanto le estoy avisando al usuario que no existe el username sin haberlo tipiado.

aca **component.ts**

```js
form: FormGroup;
usernameExist: boolean = true;

constructor(
    public userService: UserService
  ) {
    this.buildForm();

    this.form.get('username').valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(350)
    )
    .subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
      this.userService.existUsername(value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if(res){
          console.log("el username es valido: " + res);
          this.usernameExist = true;
        }else{
          console.log("el username no es valido: " + res);
          this.usernameExist = false;
        }     
      }),
      err => console.error('Error en la db al verificar el username ' + err);
    });

  }
  
   buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(15)]],
    });
  }
```

aca la view **component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login($event)">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="username"
    [(ngModel)]="username"
    placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
  />
  <div *ngIf="usernameExist" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    nombre de usuario valido.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!usernameExist" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    No existe el nombre de usuario
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="form.get('username').errors && form.get('username').dirty">
    <p
      class="text-center mt-1 text-danger"
      *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('required')"
    >
      <small>Este campo es obligatorio!</small>
    </p>
    <p
      class="text-center mt-1 text-danger"
      *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('maxlength')"
    >
      <small>El nombre de usuario es muy largo!</small>
    </p>
    <p
      class="text-center mt-1 text-danger"
      *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('minlength')"
    >
      <small>necesita un minimo 5 caracteres!</small>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar los estados de modificación de los formulario de angular, en este caso creo que es conveniente `dirty`, básicamente lo que hace `dirty` es comprobar si el usuario ha modificado el valor de un campo del formulario.

```
  <div *ngIf="usernameExist && form.get('username').dirty" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    nombre de usuario valido.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!usernameExist && form.get('username').dirty" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    No existe el nombre de usuario
  </div>
```

Comment: Gracias Franco, es cierto olvide de poner form.get('username').dirty